# Can't get input field value using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I seem to have a problem with getting field value using javascript and i think the facebook popup jquery script is blocking it but i don't know why...

I would appreciate if someone could help me out because right now im about to tear my hair off.

```
<input type="text" id="photo_album_name" style="width: 280px; height: 20px; color: #525252;" />
<textarea id="photo_album_desc" style="width: 280px; height: 100px; color: #525252;"></textarea>

function submit_photoalbum()
{
    var albumname = document.getElementById('photo_album_name').value; 
    var albumdesc = document.getElementById('photo_album_desc').value;

    alert("Album name: "+ albumname + ", Album Desc: " + albumdesc);
}
```

**You can view a live example at http://goo.gl/op6r4**

Comment: Start using frameworks like JQuery

Comment: If you're running your javascript on load and not on an event, the two elements above will have no value, as they don't have a value attribute.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is that you have mutiple elements with the same id => **invalid HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="photo_album_name" style="width: 280px; height: 20px; color: #525252;">
<input type="text" id="photo_album_name" style="width: 280px; height: 20px; color: #525252;">

<textarea id="photo_album_desc" style="width: 280px; height: 100px; color: #525252;"></textarea>
<textarea id="photo_album_desc" style="width: 280px; height: 100px; color: #525252;"></textarea>
```

Comment: @keune. in the [live example](http://goo.gl/op6r4) he linked in his question. look at the HTML.

Comment: Huh? i don't see that at all or am i blind?

Comment: I don't see it either, there are no duplicate ID's on the page I'm redirected to ?

Comment: @adeneo. I see it when i open the popup window.

Comment: Yeah, been looking for it, and found it, the facebox script creates elements with the same ID's as the one's that are already there.

Comment: @adeneo. all those downvoters, the only true and valid answer... well you can't please everyone.

Comment: Nope, but removing the original elements does'nt seem to work either, seems like that script is cloning the elements or something, anyway, this is the right answer and identifies where the problem is.

Comment: @adeneo. I don't know this plugin, but using class instead of id can solve the problem.

Comment: Yes, the facebox is making a copy and duplicating the ids.

Comment: @gdoron How do you see that? are you using some kind of program? ugh why would this stupid facebox create duplicate ID's, to me that's just dumb?

Comment: @John. I see it with chrome developers tool. and it's not just you, I think it's dumb as well...

Comment: Im going to check out that tool, would there be a easy way to change the facebox script to not make duplicate ID's or it's just built that way? Best Regards John

Comment: @John. Don't know, never used that plugin. the developer tool is built-in with the chrome browser. watch out from unreliable plugins...

Comment: @gdoron Thanks for your help "var albumname = $("#facebox #photo_album_name").val();" did the trick! and thanks to everyone else who helped!

Answer (score 0):

You need to run your function on some event where the elements have value, or add value to them  if you are running this on load.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/8NjBA/)

Comment: Answered a little too quickly, just testet the code and got a response when I added a value to the elements, and figured that was the problem. gdoron has already identified what the probably cause for not being able to retrieve the elements is.

Answer (score 0):

change the input to:

```
<input class="photo_album_name" style="width: 280px; height: 20px; color: #525252;" type="text"/>
```

and

```
<textarea class="photo_album_desc" style="width: 280px; height: 100px; color: #525252;"/>
```

and your selector to:

```
   var albumname = $('#facebox').find('.photo_album_name').val(); 
   var albumdesc = $('#facebox').find('.photo_album_desc').val();
```

Note this duplicate ID also:

```
<input id="add" style="padding-bottom: 3px; padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 5px; font-size: 13px; margin-right: 15px; padding-top: 3px;" onclick="submit_photoalbum();" type="button" value="Create Photo Album"/>
```

change to:

```
<input class="add" style="padding-bottom: 3px; padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 5px; font-size: 13px; margin-right: 15px; padding-top: 3px;" onclick="submit_photoalbum();" type="button" value="Create Photo Album"/>
```

Comment: Hello Mark

I did try that too and if do that it wont even trigger the submit_photoalbum();

Answer (score -1):

Ok.. It seems that you're replicating your form. You have it on your HTML and when you call the facebox it replicates the hidden HTML. This replicates the ID's (as gdoron was stating).

It may be a good practice to use another framework, or to change the jQuery plugin to a more stable one (like http://fancybox.net). Anyways. You can change your submit_photoalbum function to:

```
function submit_photoalbum()
{
    var albumname = $("#facebox > input").val(); 
    var albumdesc = $("#facebox > textarea").val();

    alert("Album name: "+ albumname + ", Album Desc: " + albumdesc);
}
```

It's a bit hardcoded but it'll work for this.

Comment: You just changed his code to jQuery to do the same thing with slower code. how did you fix his problem???

Comment: Really? How slower could it be to do it with jQuery. He is already loading the framework.

Comment: [look at this test](http://jsperf.com/getelementbyid-vs-jquery-id/5). anyway the main problem with your answer is that it just doesn't fix anything.

Comment: I've updated the answer =) You were right. I didn't put you a -1 since I can't. But I removed it. It's replicating the IDs

Answer (score -2):

Since you are using jQuery anyway I would just try to grab the value using jQuery so it should be:
`var albumname = $('#photo_album_name').val();`

Comment: You didn't even try it, did you?

Comment: No, your right I didn't try it. This does not work either. I saw that someone mentioned above to use .click() instead. My guess is that will not work either since the popup is hidden when the document is loaded. You may have success with .live() So you may be able to do something like:
`$("#add").live("click", function(){ var albumname = document.getElementById('photo_album_name').value; 
    var albumdesc = document.getElementById('photo_album_desc').value;

    alert("Album name: "+ albumname + ", Album Desc: " + albumdesc); });`

Comment: Neither works. See @gdoron's answer to see why it doesn't work :)

Comment: @John, have you tried moving the script after the </body> tag?